# Compute easing duration as a function of distance

Tags: javascript

I'd like some function to compute the duration for an animation such that even when the distance changes, the speed remains constant.

```
====================================
|                                  |
|<============ width =============>|
|                                  |
|         <====== distance1 ======>|
|                                  |
|               <=== distance2 ===>|
|                                  |
===================================
```

This is trivial to accomplish when dealing with linear easing,

```
function getDuration (width, distance, duration) {
  return duration * (1 - distance / width);
}
```

However, this becomes much more complex when using non-linear easing functions, such as `easeInOutQuad` (An illustration of this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/rdrbm8et/3/).

Given an easing function, such as `easeInOutQuad`, how do I compute the duration such that the speed for any distance remains constant?

```
easeInOutQuad: function (t) { return t<.5 ? 2*t*t : -1+(4-2*t)*t },
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294

[image: easeInOutQuad]

Source: http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/

Comment: Viewing from a mathematics point of view, you would have to differentiate the curve? Interesting question. :) +1

Comment: Try recording eases in excel, see what you can find. Maybe you can piece up a formula :D That's how I solved my question revolving color saturation in RGB.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you are asking for. If you have non-linear easing, the speed is not constant. So *which* speed do you want to remain constant when changing the distance?

Comment: What exactly does not work as expected when applying the trivial solution to the non-linear easing?

Comment: @bergi Take a loot at http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/rdrbm8et/3/ - the animations finish at different times. Switch the constant `EASING` to `linear` and notice how the animations finish at the same time.

Comment: Is there any documentation available for that `velocity` library you're using? I just see that you're passing completely different parameters to both calls.

Comment: I wonder how the easing function would affect the finish time. An easing function does not have anything to do with that, it is scaled to the given duration by the animation library.

Answer (score 1):

Given a function `y = f(t)`, where y is the distance and t is the time simply solve for t, and use the `t = g(y)` function to determine how long it takes to get to a given distance.

For instance, in the `easeInOutQuad` easing, `-1+(4-2*t)*t` can be solved:

[image: Solved equation]

Source: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%28y+%3D+-1%2B%284-2*t%29*t%2C+t%29

In practice, you would multiply `t` times your `duration` to get your new duration.

```
 var ratio = distance / width;
 if (ratio <= .5) {
   return duration * Math.sqrt(ratio * 1/2);
 } else if (ratio <= 1) { 
   return duration * (1 - Math.sqrt(1-ratio) / Math.sqrt(2));
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/rdrbm8et/6/

Comment: Ah, you meant to scale it so that a certain distance is reached at a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some advanced mathematics for calculate length of arc generated by formula.

Good explanation is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length). You should only use below formula

[image]

Comment: the true problem is, how do you do a differentiation in js. it's not like there is a `Math.ddx()` method. Anyway, I've found this site, might be helpful: http://oldhorse.hubpages.com/hub/drawing-calculus-numberical-integration-and-differentiation-in-javascript-part-6-in-a-series

Comment: If you have  your function defined `easeInOutQuad: function (t) { return t<.5 ? 2*t*t : -1+(4-2*t)*t },` you can calculate differentiation on paper and just use formula which you get from that

Comment: But OP obviously wanted to calculate variable ease. Else, OP wouldn't have asked.

Comment: Yes, of course my solution is for situation when you have defined easing function, but for each parametric definition of easing i Velocity.js you can discover some function: linear (this would be easy) or more complex

Comment: But differentiation and integration is definitely doable, they already exists in sites like: http://mathway.com and http://symbolab.com